# ansible: customize which password manager to use

Tags: ansible

*New to Ansible here*. I've been adapting an Ansible playbook to automate the setup of a Raspberry Pi to use Pi-hole as described [on this blog](https://ben.balter.com/2021/09/01/how-i-re-over-engineered-my-home-network/) and as per [this repo](https://github.com/benbalter/pi-hole-cloudflared-docker-compose-ansible-caddy).

One change I've made is to use Bitwarden instead of 1Password as the secrets manager (see details below).

But after having done it, and thinking of offering a PR to the repo in question, I realized that my use of Bitwarden is just as hard-coded as the use of 1Password in the original (hardly an improvement).

Is there a way to make the choice of secret manager configurable in an Ansible playbook or setup?  Or "call a different function" based on the value of a variable?

A desirable setup would be something along the lines of:

```yaml
vars:
  secret_manager: bitwarden
  # one of {'1password', 'bitwarden', 'lastpass', 'ansible-vault',
  #   'aws-secrets', 'azure-key-vault', ...}

  tasks:
    - name: ...
        ...
        value: "{{ lookup(secret_manager, item_name, field=field_name) }}"
```

### Details

Here is an example of using bitwarden instead of 1password in a `playbook.yml`:

**New:**

```yaml
  roles:
    - role: ansible-modules-bitwarden

  tasks:
    - name: "test: get 'username' from the secrets manager"
      debug:
        - msg: "{{ lookup('bitwarden', 'pi-hole', field='username') }}"
```

(and note: if the field is a custom one, one must add `custom_field=true` whereas with
`community.general.onepassword` this is not needed).

**Instead of:**

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: "test: get 'username' from the secrets manager"
      debug:
        - msg: "{{ lookup('community.general.onepassword', 'pi-hole', field='username') }}"
```

Side note and for sake of completeness, in order to make this work I needed to [install Bitwarden CLI](https://bitwarden.com/help/article/cli/#download-and-install) as well as (one of) the [ansible-modules-bitwarden](https://github.com/c0sco/ansible-modules-bitwarden#installation), and then of course log in and get a session token:

```sh
export BW_SESSION="$(bw unlock --raw)"
```

This all works fine, but I am not quite happy: now the use of Bitwarden is hard-coded instead of "1Password". I would like to make this more generic and customizable. What if someone would like to use LastPass or AWS Secrets Manager instead?

### Things I've tried

- using `if-else`:

  ```yaml
  - hosts: all
    vars:
      use_bitwarden: true
      secret_item: pi-hole

    roles:
      - role: ansible-modules-bitwarden
        when: use_bitwarden

    tasks:
      - name: get username from the secrets manager
        debug:
          msg: "{{ lookup('bitwarden', secret_item, field='username') if use_bitwarden \
          else lookup('community.general.onepassword', secret_item, field='username') }}"
  ```

  but this bloats the playbook, makes it less readable and less DRY. Also, it isn't very extensible to the many other secrets managers out there.
- define which manager to use in a variable:

  ```yaml
    - hosts: all
      vars:
        secret_manager: bitwarden
        # secret_manager: community.general.onepassword
        secret_item: pi-hole

      roles:
        - role: ansible-modules-bitwarden
          when: secret_manager == 'bitwarden'

      tasks:
        - name: get username from the secrets manager
          debug:
            msg: "{{ lookup(secret_manager, secret_item, field='username') }}"
  ```

  but this doesn't work as custom fields are to be queried with `custom_field=true` with the Bitwarden plugin, but not with 1Password.

### Other ideas (not tried)

- define a new generic plugin that uses other existing ones, based on a config variable.
- use a task to get all the needed variables from whatever password manager at once and insert them, encrypted, into Ansible's vault. That way the task that does that can be isolated and have conditional execution with `when: secret_manager == 'that'`. But it makes maintenance of the playbook more difficult.

Maybe there is a much simpler and concise way of accomplishing this?